# if git clone cannot work ,what can I do?

Tags: git, clone

I installed torch using

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
```

If in China, git does not seem to work so I've to download the source as a zip file. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: If you are using git you are able take advantage of the versioning mechanisms that git provides. For example you could change the source code and "commit" it (thats the language for saving your change to the ever growing history (of changes)). Otherwise everything should be the same (except that it is compressed as a zip file)

Answer (score 1):

"clone" uses git software on your computer to download the source code and it's entire version history.

"download zip" creates a zip file of just the current version of the source code for you to download - the project history is not included.

Answer (score 0):

In China, `git` always works.

`github` was banned several years ago but now it works too.

There are two possibilities that `git` doesn't seem to work:

1) You are working behind some proxy.

In this case you need to configure your git or your system to enable your proxy.

Also, in some system, such as Ubuntu 16.04, `git` behind proxy may have some bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199

To solve this issue, you just need to remove the `git` and reinstall it from source.

2) `git clone` from `github` is too slow.

This is because there is a unstable network connection between China and `github`.

You can download a project using your browser. @mosaic101 has told you about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Git to use a proxy. [Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks) is a fast tunnel proxy that helps you bypass firewalls in China.

On Linux & Windows

- `git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'`
- `git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'`

On Mac

- `git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1086'`
- `git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1086'`